# Ngrok and webhooks

Tags: express, heroku, ngrok

I got a problem on my app, and i'm newbie on this tehcnology ...
I have an express app on a heroku url (https://my-website.heroku.com)

I've also this project on a localhost. I want to use the prismic webhook to do some stuff when a document is published.

I try to use ngrok to:

- connect it to the heroku website
- detect when my /webhook route is called on the heroku app to dispatch it on my localhost server (which is the same project, but I don't know how to do this with ngrok (I used some commands but nothing happen :/ )

Can you help me please ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your use case, but it sounds like what you're wanting to do is handle or detect an incoming request to your heroku app and then proxy or forward that request to your localhost.

One way to handle this would be to -- in response to the original event or request -- then make a second request like a POST request to the Ngrok URL linked to your localhost machine from your heroku app. Ngrok itself is not a real proxy server, it just links two instances of URL/DOMAIN:PORT to each other where one of these runs in the Ngrok cloud service.

So in the code you have handling or receiving the webhook request on the heroku app, you could there make, say, a POST request to the Ngrok URL for your localhost and that request would be forwarded to your localhost machine. I'm not sure what data or information you want to see in localhost but you could pass along any incoming request data in the POST body to your localhost Ngrok URL and then see the same data locally.

Comment: that's what I want to do, I'll try what you're explaining :) thank's